# Trouble differentiating Rspec's 'let' vs 'let!'

Tags: rspec, let

I have read the [rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) and have searched a number of other places but I am having a difficult time grasping the difference between Rspec's `let` and `let!`

I've read that `let` isn't initialized until it's needed and that its value is only cached per example. I've also read that `let!` forces the variable into immediate existence, and forces invocation for each example. I guess since I'm new, I'm having a difficult time seeing how this relates to the following examples. Why does `:m1` need to be set with `let!` to assert `m1.content` is present on the page, but `:user` can be set with `let`to assert that the page contains `text: user.name`?

```
  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
    let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

    describe "microposts" do
      it { should have_content(m1.content) }
      it { should have_content(m2.content) }
      it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
    end
  end

  describe "after saving the user" do
    before { click_button submit }
    let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_success_message('Welcome') } 
    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the before block is calling `visit user_path(user)` the user value gets initialized there and RSpec will visit that page. If the `:m1` `:m2` were not using `let!` then the visit would yield no content making

```
it { should have_content(m1.content) }
it { should have_content(m2.content) }
```

fail because it expects the microposts to be created before the user visits the page. `let!` allows the microposts to be created before the before block gets called and when the tests visit the page the microposts should've already been created.

Another way to write the same tests and have them pass is doing the following:

```
describe "profile page" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
  let(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

  before do
    m1
    m2
    visit user_path(user)
  end
```

calling the variables `m1` and `m2` before `visit user_path(user)` causes them to be initialized before the page is visited and causing the tests to pass.

**UPDATE**
This small example would make more sense:

In this example we are calling get_all_posts which just returns an array of posts. Notice that we're calling the method before the assertion and before the `it` block gets executed. Since post doesn't get called until the assertion is executed.

```
def get_all_posts
  Post.all
end

let(:post) { create(:post) }

before { @response = get_all_posts }

it 'gets all posts' do 
  @response.should include(post)
end
```

by using `let!` the post would get created as soon as RSpec sees the method (before the `before` block) and the post would get returned in the list of `Post`

Again, another way to do the same would be to call the variable name in the before block before we call the method

```
before do
  post
  @response = get_all_posts
end
```

as that will ensure that the `let(:post)` block gets called before the method itself is called creating the `Post` so that it gets returned in the `Post.all` call

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So, sending the object (m1) a message (content) isn't enough using let because m1 hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: Well that's not the reason why the test would fail. The reason the test fails is because you've already 'visited the page' before creating the microposts and therefore the page had no content. I could update my answer to be a little more clear on that if you still have doubts?

Comment: Well, after looking again at my question ("after saving the user") again, how would the second test be able to check for 'user.name'?

Comment: In a way, the fact is that let executes the block you pass it and assigns the result to the (:m1). The important thing is what's inside the block. Which is creating the micropost record and somewhere along the controller/view is returning that record causing the content to match what's in m1, which is the result of the `FactoryGirl.create(:microposts)`

Comment: I understand your answer, but I'm still confused how the test, ("after saving the user") is able to call 'user.name' if it's only using 'let'? I thought the let block doesn't execute until you call 'user' somewhere? Is this not the case when user.name is within in the same block as let??? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm obviously missing something?

Comment: Notice that the let(:user) in that case is doing `User.find_by` not creating a user so when you call user it goes to find the user. I'm assuming the Submit button is creating the user and then the test is just testing the inclusion of the title selector with the user name found by querying the db.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I guess I need to explore this a bit more to fully understand. Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The key to differentiate is just how rspec performs the steps.

Look at the code again:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

before { visit user_path(user) }
```

If we use let instead of let!, m1 and m2 are not created at the moment. Rspec then does a visit and the page is loaded, but obviously there is no m1 nor m2 on the page.

So now if we call m1 and m2, they will be created in memory. But it's already too late since the page is not going to be loaded again unless we purposely do so. Hence any UI test on the page will result in failure.