# Rspec: let versus let with an exclamation mark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

Can comeone explain to me why it is necessary to use let! as opposed to let in this case? The test only passes when I include the !. I thought I understood that let would automatically execute before each "it" statement within that block, but apparently that is not the case.

```
describe Artist do

  before do
  @artist = Artist.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                 password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end
  subject { @artist }

  describe "virtual requests" do
    let!(:virtual1) { FactoryGirl.create(:virtual_request, artist: @artist ) }
    let!(:virtual2) { FactoryGirl.create(:virtual_request, artist: @artist ) }

    it "should be multiple" do
      @artist.virtual_requests.count.should == 2 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: found a great explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407733/trouble-differentiating-rspecs-let-vs-let

Comment: why isnt artist in a `let`?

Comment: I had to use a .dup method at some point in the spec, doesn't work with a let variable, so I switched it up to a instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `let` is lazy. If you don't call it, it won't do anything.

Instead, `let!` is active and will execute the code inside its block when you pass by.

In your code, if you replace `let!` with `let`, your test won't pass.

The reason is you havn't called `:virtual1` and `:virtual2` afterwards, so the code inside there block won't be executed and the record won't be created by FactoryGirl.

Comment: Often, if you find that you are using `let!`, you really should be using `before` instead. If you always need to execute code, it belongs in the `before`. Also note that you never actually use your let variables, so they don't even need a name.